# hyper-v 2012 r2 datacenter license

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am trying to set up a virtual machine to use automatic activation. This is the first time I have done this, and I got the following error:

---

### Windows Script Host

### Error: 0xC004F050 The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is invalid

I have a physical computer that has the following OS: "Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter".
on this computer I enabled the role of "Hyper-V manager".
I refer to the server as my Hyper-V server.

On the server I installed a guest (virtual) machine. The guest OS is Windows 7 x64.
The host machine (my "Hyper-V server") is activated.
Windows on the guest machine as not activated.

I am trying to utilize the automatic activation feature as described in [Automatic Virtual Machine Activation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303421.aspx).

If I understand correctly, my setup should allow me to use and activate an unlimited number of virtual machines under the license of the Hyper-V server.

I am trying to use the keys specified in the article, but getting the error. Obviously I am doing something very basic, very wrong.

Comment: Do not close it - this is not a legal licensing question just a "pseudo admin" who has no idea about the technical side and just copy/pasted a wrong KMS Client key.... so please do not vote to close.

Comment: You're trying to license Windows 7 against a Windows Server key - this does not work. You don't have the rights to use Windows 7, unless you have a different volume license agreement for it. You must use Windows Server (Datacenter or Standard) on all VM's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an AVMA key from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303421.aspx.

You can use it to activate server 2012 R2 datacentre on a properly-licensed Hyper-V host; it will activate against Hyper-V and not your KMS, SLIC, or Microsoft.  However, it can be used only to activate server 2012 R2 datacentre.

If I'm reading you correctly, **you are trying to activate Windows 7 with this key.  It will not work**.  The key is specific to the guest OS, and the error you get is telling you the key is not valid for windows 7.  There is no AVMA key or support for windows 7, so you will have to use some other type of key (such as a KMS key, assuming you have a KMS).

If that's not it and you are in fact trying to activate server 2012 R2 datacentre, do this:

Check your Hyper-V server's logs to see if anything is the matter there.  However, the most likely cause is that you have not actually directed the server to activate; try this:

```
slmgr /ato
```

That will direct the VM to activate, and in a short time will generally return a message either saying activation was successful or giving an error code indicating why it failed.

You can also inspect the KVP on the host; you have to do this with a script.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/11/18/hyper-v-script-looking-at-kvp-guestintrinsicexchangeitems.aspx.

Additionally, you can check the guest's windows event logs for event ID 12309, which might contain some indication of why it won't activate.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Auto Activation on a client OS such as Windows 7.

This is also NOT covered by MS Datacenter Edition licensing.

You are only entitled to use the DataCenter licensing with Windows Server based  VMs as guest Operating Systems. Hence Auto Activation on Windows Server 2012R2 will only work on an operating system as a VM that supports this mechanism - e.g. a VM running Windows Server 2012R2!

You may have downgrade licensing to cover other Windows Server VMs such as Server 2008R2 but they do not support Auto Activation.